# Android App List View, Show Action Taken On Search Results

Tags: android, user-interface, mobile-application

On a job search application for Android phones, we have a search results screen with items as rows in a list view.

Ideally, I need a way to mark these items after a user has applied to the job.

In iOS we used a simple text indicator on the row on the right side. But that is not exactly "Android," it is more common on iOS.

Anyone have any reference for Android or perhaps have a design solution?

[[image: mockup]]

Comment: Please consider adding the image instead of an external link next time. The link might get discontinued and lower the quality of the question/answer ;)

Comment: I don't have the solution but I suggest you to use the Material Desing as design reference http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists-controls.html

Comment: Yes, adding the image would be good. But Stack does not permit that for new users. STACK adds the link, not me.

Yes, I am quite familiar with material design and documentation. This is not detailed there. Hence asking the question here.

Comment: You're right, this is not detailed. But reading the specification I think you should use the right side and put whatever you want, e.g, a surrounded "APPLIED" text. "Supplemental actions (the right side of a list tile): Are functionally consistent throughout tiles in a specific list, e.g, an icon that indicates whether someone is online; are represented in tiles with icons, secondary text, etc.". if the suplemental is not a toggle "avoid creating visual noise... e.g, by displaying a share action in every tile".